# RewriteRule doesn't like multiple words

Tags: php, .htaccess, search, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Ok I have a problem using $_GET with htaccess. If I search for "post title" i go to 
http://site.com/search/post%20title
and this line:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) search.php?post_title=$1
```

Would create that $_GET but it only does so for the first word if I:

```
echo $_GET['post_title'];
```

I only get the first word how would I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+) search.php?post_title=$1
```

This defines a space as `\s`

Answer (score 2):

Add a space to your character class:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z0-9 _-]+) search.php?post_title=$1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, ` ` is not a valid regex character within a character class.

Comment: Really? I tested it a moment ago. Is that a PHP thing?

Comment: That is the difference between javascript regex and preg regex.